# Show that the image of a homeomorphism involving the Cantor function has a certain measure

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, cantor-set

Currently working on the task of showing the following:
Let $f$ be the Cantor function and $$g: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1], x \mapsto \frac{f(x)+x}{2}$$

Then $\lambda(g(C)) = \frac{1}{2}$

where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.
I've already shown that $g$ is a homeomorphism and that $\lambda(f(C)) = 1$ but I'm struggling to prove the rest.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: the image of $f/2$ has measure $1/2$ and the Cantor set has measure zero...

Comment: Yeah sure, but why should I be able to swap measure and function? Thats not really obvious to me

Comment: this is true when one set has measure zero  (in other words if $C=x+y, x \in A, y\in B, \lambda(B)=0$ then $\lambda(C)=\lambda(A)$ - the above of course in the sense that $x$ is summed with a unique $y$ as here not as sum set